# in linux 2.6.34 kernel or the older version, who send a scsi cmd to open the door when pressing the eject button of cdrom?

Tags: kernel

The scsi cmd is something like 0x1b 0x00 0x00 0x02.

I am trying to study the kernel, but can not make clear.

Is there a interrupt produced when pressing or someone is polling the status of the cdrom ?

I think it is not sent by some app invoked by udev rules like the the new system.

Answer (score 0):

The eject button is handled by the drive itself. You can prevent a drive from handling eject presses by locking the media (command 1E, prevent/allow medium removal; `scsi_set_medium_removal` in the kernel), which the kernel does when a CD is mounted, but apart from that software isn't involved in handling ejection in reaction to pressing the eject button on the drive.

In kernel version 2.6.34, the SCSI load/unload (eject) command is called `GPCMD_START_STOP_UNIT`, and you'll find it used in `sr_tray_move` in `drivers/scsi/sr_ioctl.c`.

Comment: There's the `eject` command which can trigger a software eject.

Comment: Thanks @Shadur, I was referring only to hardware ejection; I've clarified my answer. (`eject` uses command 1B which the OP mentioned.)

Comment: Thanks! @Stephen Kitt,           what i want to know is that how the scsi driver know the eject button is pressed, is there a interrupt produced to tell the scsi driver or scsi use a timer to poll the status of cdrom ?

Comment: the version i asked is the linux kernel 2.6.34 or the older version. i know how it works in the newest version. but can not find the code send the scsi cmd to eject in the older kernel version.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what you're after then, but I've added the location of the SCSI eject code in 2.6.34.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt,          i don't think you are right. Because i just add the debug info in sr_tray_move. it did not print the debug info when pressing eject button. You can  check who calls that function, you will find it can not be called when pressing eject button.

Comment: Yes, like I said right from the beginning, there is no software involved in handling the eject button. You press the eject button, and the drive ejects the tray, it doesn't ask the kernel to do anything.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt,     Thank you very much!    Do you mean that after initializing , the hardware (drive) will handle the events of pressing eject button ? if yes , i have a question below:

Comment: There's no initialisation involved. You can check yourself: put a CD in a drive, close the tray, reboot your system, then before the OS loads, push the eject button: the drive will eject the CD, without any software being available to even initialise the drive.

Comment: the cdrom is not be locked, if the drive can not open the door when pressing eject button, does that mean the initializing of the hardware is not correct ?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt, thanks!  thank you very much!   i know it works without any software even initialise the drive.